# which one is the best practice to setup Django and Scrapy projects?

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I'm working on a project in which scrapy code just has to crawl data from web and store it into database and django application just need to show it as website, both codes(scrapy and django) have nothing to do with each other. I'm wondering  what would be the best practice to setup these two parts of the project? Options are:

- Create both of them in same folder
- Create scrapy project inside Django project

Guide me. Thanks

Comment: no need to create both projects in the same folder as long as their database is common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Pramod has pointed out, there is no necessity that they should be in the same folder. But I'll advise you to take the first option - "Both projects in same folder".

My arguments are:

- I'd advice against the second option because, it'd just complicate the django project. As django is a framework, there is a default folder structure and implicit meanings in a django project that is time-tested.
  why mess with that?
- Its better to have two parts of the project in the same folder as it makes more sense as a project.